# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'flask' when trying to up docker

Tags: python, docker, flask

I'm using docker for the first time to mount my project and I'm having a problem:

```
project    | Traceback (most recent call last):
project    |   File "app.py", line 2, in <module>
project    |     from flask import Flask, jsonify, request
project    | ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'flask'
```

When I do:
    `sudo docker-compose up`

I really have the code:
    `from flask import Flask, jsonify, request`

But I put in my requirements:

```
SQLAlchemy
flask
flask-graphql
flask-migrate
flask-sqlalchemy
graphene
graphene-sqlalchemy
mysqlclient
Flask-GraphQL-Auth
flask_jwt
```

I`ve try to force the version too:

```
flask==1.1.1
```

And my docker Dockerfile have:

```
FROM python:3.6
COPY . /app
WORKDIR /app
RUN python3 -m pip install --upgrade pip
EXPOSE 5000
ENTRYPOINT ["python"]
CMD ["app.py"]
```

And I see in the logs from `sudo docker-compose build`:

```
Step 4/7 : RUN python3 -m pip install --upgrade pip
 ---> Running in df146c97e8fa
Requirement already up-to-date: pip in /usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages (20.0.2)
```

I have no idea why this problem is happening. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Add requirements.txt in your Dockerfile**

```
FROM python:3.6
COPY . /app
WORKDIR /app
RUN pip install --upgrade pip
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt
EXPOSE 5000
ENTRYPOINT ["python"]
CMD ["app.py"]
```

Answer (score 1):

You aren't installing the requirements in your dockerfile, so the dockerized environment doesn't have Flask.

Add

```
RUN python3 -m pip install -r /app/requirements.txt
```

after the current `RUN python3 -m pip install --upgrade pip` line.